# UITableView control Reloading Header

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem, I have added to the header of the UITableView a banner from the internet, the problem is that every reload of the banner give me a new one, my question is can I control the reloading issue of the tableview, I don't want every time that when I scroll the table view I get dynamic reloading, I want to load all the tableview once.

thanks,

Comment: Can you provide us the code which creates the "banner from the internet".

Comment: sorry I can't post code, because I cant post any code from my job applications

Answer (score 1):

You can not prevent UITableView of reloading the header file. Therefore you have to create a UIView subclass (e.g. MyHeaderView) that represents your header view. MyHeaderView loads the data from the internet and stores all necessary information (images, text, ...) in ivars. It also has a method to reload the data from the internet so you can call it if necessary. Finally you assign MyHeaderView to the UITableView's `setTableHeaderView:`.

Comment: thats what I did I get the content in the init and verytime header loads the same content so user don't see difference

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood. The problem is, that every time the UITableView scrolls back to top, the header view gets reloaded. And you want the header view to load just once. Without seeing any code snippet it's hard to suggest where the problem comes from. Where do you assign your custom header view to the tableView's tableHeaderView?